# How to limit logging level via processors?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elastic-beats

I use [`journalbeat`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/current/index.html) to ship `journald` events to logstash (and then ultimately to elasticsearch). I am interested only in higher priority messages.

At the very top of my `journalbeat.yml` file I have

```
processors:
 - drop_event:
     when:
        range:
          syslog.priority.gte: 5
```

My intent was to run a processor (on all events) which would drop events which have a `syslog.priority` field greater or equal to `5` (= drop `debug` and `info` messages).

This apparently does not work because I see messages such as

```
{
  "_index": "journalbeat-7.1.0-2019.05.28-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "mlHv_moBGanrPHbULpIO",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2019-05-28T14:54:07.866Z",
    "systemd": {
      "slice": "system.slice",
      "unit": "docker.service",
      "transport": "stdout",
      "cgroup": "/system.slice/docker.service",
      "invocation_id": "6b251fbc93814b26b857e33f79f261d2"
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "agent": {
      "ephemeral_id": "468fbf6d-8a90-47d2-8aff-a65d77c316c2",
      "hostname": "srv",
      "id": "c0526522-ca71-4a2a-a0e5-aa33f1e7c76e",
      "version": "7.1.0",
      "type": "journalbeat"
    },
    "message": "time=\"2019-05-28T16:54:07.866182040+02:00\" level=info msg=\"NetworkDB stats srv(cc5972674014) - netID:gpnvf5y5wthv491ypvpzunbot leaving:false netPeers:1 entries:2 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0\"",
    "journald": {
      "custom": {
        "stream_id": "2e5695063ac54814a73ca48966594789",
        "selinux_context": "unconfined\n"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "created": "2019-05-28T14:54:07.907Z"
    },
    "host": {
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "hostname": "srv",
      "id": "77c0caf0e493e9cd0f7c689856d9e916",
      "boot_id": "a51ba1fe7c884be685c53329db0f036b",
      "name": "srv",
      "os": {
        "codename": "bionic",
        "platform": "ubuntu",
        "version": "18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)",
        "family": "debian",
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "kernel": "4.15.0-50-generic"
      },
      "containerized": false
    },
    "syslog": {
      "facility": 3,
      "priority": 6,
      "identifier": "dockerd"
    },
    "process": {
      "pid": 7607,
      "name": "dockerd",
      "uid": 0,
      "cmd": "/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375",
      "executable": "/usr/bin/dockerd-ce",
      "capabilites": "3fffffffff"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-05-28T14:54:07.866Z"
    ],
    "event.created": [
      "2019-05-28T14:54:07.907Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1559055247866
  ]
}
```

being sent to elasticsearch (and which I then see through kibana). Please note the

```
    "syslog": {
      "facility": 3,
      "priority": 6,
      "identifier": "dockerd"
    },
```

section which is then resolved to `syslog.priority: 6` in kibana.

**How should the processor be connected to "all events"?**

Comment: Could you provide the full configuration file of journalbeat?

Comment: I've just the same problem but instead of using processors I'm using Logstash filters. Anyway, the issue is the same: filter about priority is ignored. In fact, I've filled an issue in Logstash's github (this is it: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11744) because I was sure it was its fault, although now I'm not so sure if using processors have the same behaviour. Anyway, what it's sure something wrong is happening when syslog priority is handled by some (beat?, logstash?) ELK Stack piece